How to edit multiple videos in bulk?
The tasks are

Trim few seconds from the end of the video.
Add default outro.
Render.

I want this same steps done for a lot of videos. Is there a way to automate this?
p.s. I've seen folks suggesting ffmpeg for similar tasks. But I'm looking for something with user interface; I'm not familiar with command line, and don't have time now to dive into it.

Do you trim exactly the same number of seconds from the end of each video? Or does it vary?

@tomh hi, yes, it's the same for all videos. 1 second and 15 milliseconds. I did try to use ffmpeg, but can't figure out make it count from the end of the video.

I know you don't want to use ffmpeg, so I'm not putting this as an answer, but this get duration of files as a variable: https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds#945604

I know you don't want to use ffmpeg, so I'm not putting this as an answer, but this get duration of files as a variable: https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds#945604

Joining files together with FFmpeg is called Concatenating. See here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
